# Pointers to a class within void function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance

I am learning how classes/inheritances/pointers work in C++ and coding the following.

I have a class  **unit** declared as such:

```
class unit{
    public:
        int locationX,locationY;

        //genotype (does not change)
        float agility, build,size,stamina, aggression;
        //phenotype (changes based on genotype and stimuli)
        float speed, strength, hunger;
};
```

When I create a new instance to pass into a void function (below, respectively), the memory is not allocated yet.

**Instance**

```
unit **units = 0;
```

**Void Function Prototype**

```
void initialize(grid *grids, unit **units /*, plant **plants, predator **predators */);
```

The memory is allocated within the void function using some parameters:

```
void initialize(grid *grids, unit **units,plant **plants,predator **predators)
{
    units = new unit*[int(((grids->gridHeight)*(grids->gridWidth)*(grids->gridDivision))/20)];

    for(register int i = 0; i<int(((grids->gridHeight)*(grids->gridWidth)*(grids->gridDivision))/20); i++)
        {
        units[i] = new unit;
        units[i]->hunger = 5;
        units[i]->locationX = (rand()%((grids->gridWidth)-0));
        units[i]->locationY = (rand()%((grids->gridHeight)-0));
        //etc, etc
    }
}
```

However, once I exit the void function, the data I just stored gets deleted. Is there something wrong with the pointer declarations and passing into the function (which is as follows)?

```
initialize(&environment, units, plants, predators);
```

**NOTE**: I only have problems with the *units* variable declared under **unit** class. The *environment* variable is fine. The other two (*plants* and *predators*) are similar to *units*, so if this is fixed, I can fix the others.

**Second Note**: The main function is as follows (relevant parts):

```
int main()
{
    unit **units = 0; //<--- Important one
    plant **plants = 0;
    predator **predators = 0;
    grid environment(250,250,5); //Constructor for environment (don't mind this)
    initialize(&environment, units, plants, predators); //<-- Void function
    running = true;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help/links/explanations you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `units` into the function **by value**. This means that the `units` pointer within the function starts out as a copy of the one in the calling code. Within the function you assign a new value to the local `units` variable (i.e. the address of some newly created objects). Then when the function terminates, the local variable passes out of scope and the objects it pointed to are lost. The pointer in the calling code is never modified, and knows nothing about any of this.

Pass it by reference instead:

```
void initialize(grid *grids, unit ** &units)
```

Comment: In addition to working as intended, it will save some overhead

Answer (score 1):

You're passing "units" as a type "unit**" which is on the stack. When you assign a new value to the variable "units", you're affecting the variable local to the function. If you want the calling code to have it's variable "units" updated, you must pass it in by pointer or by reference.

Easiest way to fix this is to change your function signature to:

```
void initialize(grid *grids, unit **&units, etc.. );
```

this is passing the variable units as a reference to a pointer to a pointer to a unit.

Comment: "passing the variable units as a reference to a pointer to a pointer to a unit": So I think you also mean `unit ** &units`, not `units * &units` :-)

Comment: Oops yes! thanks (turned out to be a text formatting problem)

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a pointer (or array) `A * a` inside a method is a particular case of modifying your variable `a` (which is a pointer/array in this case). Modifying a variable inside a method can be done either by passing a pointer to it, or a reference to it. So in the case your variable is already a pointer, these two options are the following.

By passing a pointer to your pointer `a`:

```
void init(A * *a)
{
    *a = new A(); // or "new A[n]" if "a" is an array
}

void main()
{
    A * a;
    init(&a);
}
```

Or passing a reference to your pointer:

```
void init(A * &a)
{
    a = new A();  // or "new A[n]" if "a" is an array
}

void main()
{
    A * a;
    init(a);
}
```

So in your case, `a` is an array of `unit*` (which I think is a bad design by the way, it would be better to simply use an array of `unit` and save you from this loop to dynamically allocate separately all units), so basically `a` is of type `unit **` so your `A` is actually the type `unit*`. Using the second method would lead to:

```
void init(unit* * &units)
```

But as I said, it is probably better to simply use an array of `unit` instead, and your whole code would look like:

```
void initialize(unit * &units /* etc */)
{
    // note that I use unit instead of unit* here
    units = new unit[n];

    for(register int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        // note that I remove the "new unit;" here
        // note that I use "." instead of "->"
        units[i].hunger = 5;
        units[i].locationX = (rand()%((grids->gridWidth)-0));
        units[i].locationY = (rand()%((grids->gridHeight)-0));
        //etc, etc
    }
}

void main()
{
    unit * units;
    initialize(units);
}
```